# Linq With TakeWhile in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, c#-4.0

What is best way to get list of best cards for example I want to get gift cards to apply for order total 100. It should return best combination like 30+40+75. below is my current code which stopped after `30+40 = 70` which is wrong because order total is more then 70 so we can not apply two gifts cards only. it should return 3 gift cards as shown above.

```
[Test]
public void GetBestAvailableGiftCards()
{
    var list = new List<GiftCard>
    {
        new GiftCard() {CardNumber = "45964123358448514", SecurityCode = "032443", Balance = 75},
        new GiftCard() {CardNumber = "45964123345954414", SecurityCode = "032443", Balance = 85},
        new GiftCard() {CardNumber = "45964062845645735", SecurityCode = "435448", Balance = 40},
        new GiftCard() {CardNumber = "28872034245533173", SecurityCode = "934465", Balance = 30}
    };

    var orderTotal = 100;
    double current = 0;
    var cards = list
        .OrderBy(x => x.Balance)
        .TakeWhile(card => (current = current + card.Balance) <= orderTotal)
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Is it giving you incorrect results? What output do you expect?

Comment: It stops there because the next result is `30+40+75` which is greater than 100 (which is what your check is).

Comment: Why the correct result is 3 cards? 30+40+75 = 145, which is GREATER then 100.

Comment: 30+40+75 <= 100????

Comment: actually as u know it gift cards ... so we should apply multiple gift cards which satsify order total

Comment: What you are trying to solve is know as the _[Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)_ (more specifically it's the _[Subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)_). I suggest you read up on that before trying a half-hearted solution.

Comment: Btw, what company are you doing the algorithm for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the usual behavior of [`TakeWhile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548775(v=vs.100).aspx), it returns elements from a sequence as long as a specified condition is true.

You have to *tweak* this a bit to include the next addition(which makes condition true).

```
    var orderTotal = 100;
    double current = 0;
    var cards = list
        .OrderBy(x => x.Balance)
        .TakeWhile(card => 
         {              
            bool returnvalue = current < orderTotal; 
            current += card.Balance;
            return returnvalue;
        })
        .ToList();
```

Check this [`example`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MoLXmq)

Comment: it has to be `bool returnvalue = current < orderTotal;`  not `<=`

Answer (score 1):

If I'm getting your question right, you are trying to select some subset of your giftcards such that sum of their balances is as close to `orderTotal` as possible, by still less or equal `orderTotal`. In the given case, the best option would be to just give to the user the 85-card, as no other combination seems better to me.

Sadly, this cannot be solved simply by straightforward use of LINQ. If this is not a NP-hard problem, try using some dynamic algorithm.